# gem install rawr fails?

Tags: jruby

```
Successfully installed rawr-1.4.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rawr-1.4.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rawr-1.4.3...
Could not find main page README.md
Could not find main page README.md
Could not find main page README.md
Could not find main page README.md
```

however when I run rawr install, it says

```
No command 'rawr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'raw' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'rar' from package 'rar' (multiverse)
rawr: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

`jruby -S rawr install`